# How to put a div next to a mat-label

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular project in which I'm using Angular Material.

I need to put a div in the same line as a mat-label but I don't know how to do that.

This is what I'm trying to achieve (the box with the lighter blue background color is the div I'm talking about):

[image: a mat-form-field with a mat-label and a div on the same line]

This is what I have so far:

[image: a mat-form-field with a mat-label and a div on different lines]

My html:

```
  <div class="container__irr--holding">
    <span>موجودی ریالی:</span>
    <span>
     100,000,000
    </span>
  </div>

  <mat-label>پرداختی</mat-label>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    // I haven't included code for mat-form-field to make sample code more readable and shorter
  </mat-form-field>
```

My scss:

```
.container__irr--holding {
      display: flex;
      background: #465490;
      padding: 2px;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to add `justify-content: space-between;` to `.container__irr--holding`

```
.container__irr--holding {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #465490;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

then modify the html to look like this:

```
  <div class="container__irr--holding">
    <div>
    <span>موجودی ریالی:</span>
    <span>
     100,000,000
    </span>
    </div>
    <mat-label>پرداختی</mat-label>
  </div>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eld5pj?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

## Using a flex-layout container to align block-level elements

You can achieve this pretty easily by adding a wrapping div with a flex-layout surrounding the two elements you want to bring onto the same line:

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div>Same line div</div>
  <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
</div>
```

```css
.flex-wrapper {
 display: flex;
justify-content: space-between
}
```

#### Alternate Approach

add a style-rule to display the elements as inline-block.

```html
<div class="inline">Other Div</div>
<mat-label class="inline">Inline Label</mat-label>
```

```css
mat-label.inline, div.inline  {
  display: inline-block;
}
```